# UICollectionViewController seque to UIViewController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewController and UIViewController, with the UINavigationController as root.

When I click on a UICollectionViewCell, it pushes the UIViewController

The snippet of code I have for that is:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

    MyViewController *myVC = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;


}
```

But it crashes when I click on the cell and says

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController"

I thought by making the UINavigationController root solves this. What am i doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out actually

went into Editor at the top toolbar, then Embed In, then navigation controller
voila